# Cordys BPM - Create an E-mail Model based on an XML Schema Document

Tags: business-process-management

I have created a standalone email model and generated a web service based on the email model. I followed the same steps as described in the Cordys documentation ( https://wiki.cordys.com/display/bop41/Creating+an+E-mail+Model ) but when I try to invoke the web service I am getting a fault like  "Do not understand method TAT_Email_Model_WebserviceOperation of type NSCUST".

I have linked my WebServiceInterface to  an Email service container ( correct me if I am done wrong over here).

The complete description of the fault is as below. Any suggestions.

```
<ErrorDetails>
  <Request>
    <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <SOAP:Header xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <header xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
          <Logger xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/" />
        </header>
        <i18n:international xmlns:i18n="http://www.w3.org/2005/09/ws-i18n">
          <locale xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/09/ws-i18n">en-US</locale>
        </i18n:international>
      </SOAP:Header>
      <SOAP:Body>
        <TAT_Email_Model_WebserviceOperation xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/email">
          <SOURCE>Notification Custom Method</SOURCE>
          <MESSAGE_DATA>
            <Application>
              <data>
                <message_data />
                <message_metadata />
              </data>
            </Application>
          </MESSAGE_DATA>
          <SUBJECT>PARAMETER</SUBJECT>
          <attachments>
            <attachment name="" encoded="false">PARAMETER</attachment>
          </attachments>
          <SENDER_ADDRESS>
            <MAIL_ID>PARAMETER</MAIL_ID>
            <DISPLAY_NAME>PARAMETER</DISPLAY_NAME>
          </SENDER_ADDRESS>
          <RECEIVERS>
            <MAILING_LIST>
              <to>
                <address>
                  <displayName>PARAMETER</displayName>
                  <emailAddress>PARAMETER</emailAddress>
                </address>
              </to>
              <cc>
                <address>
                  <displayName>PARAMETER</displayName>
                  <emailAddress>PARAMETER</emailAddress>
                </address>
              </cc>
              <bcc>
                <address>
                  <displayName>PARAMETER</displayName>
                  <emailAddress>PARAMETER</emailAddress>
                </address>
              </bcc>
            </MAILING_LIST>
          </RECEIVERS>
        </TAT_Email_Model_WebserviceOperation>
      </SOAP:Body>
    </SOAP:Envelope>
  </Request>
  <Response>
    <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <SOAP:Header xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <header xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
          <msg-id>000C297F-0536-11E3-E944-DF0951D0118E</msg-id>
          <license>License has expired since 138 day(s)</license>
        </header>
      </SOAP:Header>
      <SOAP:Body>
        <SOAP:Fault>
          <faultcode>MustUnderstand</faultcode>
          <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Do not understand method TAT_Email_Model_WebserviceOperation of type NSCUST</faultstring>
          <faultactor>http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/email</faultactor>
          <detail>
            <cordys:FaultDetails xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
              <cordys:LocalizableMessage xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
                <cordys:MessageCode xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/" />
              </cordys:LocalizableMessage>
            </cordys:FaultDetails>
          </detail>
        </SOAP:Fault>
      </SOAP:Body>
    </SOAP:Envelope>
  </Response>
</ErrorDetails>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bound it to the wrong service container, you have to attach it to the Notification Service Container.

The error tells you that the current handling service container cannot handle requests of type NSCUST. This is available in the implementation of the webservice.

NOTE: you license has been expired on that server. With the License Manager in Cordys you can update it.